# How to compare two methods in Java

Tags: java

Am trying to compare two methods but am getting this error:

```
cannot invoke equals(void) on primitive type void
```

**Code:**

```
package rockpaper;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class game { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String rock="r";
   String paper="p";
   String scissors="s";
   userInput();
   compInput();


if(userInput().equals(compInput())){//this is where the error is//
 
   }
  }
  public static void userInput(){
  Scanner put=new Scanner(System.in);
    String user;
    System.out.println("enter your move....");
    user=put.nextLine();
    if(user.equals("r")){
      System.out.println("your move is rock");
    }
    if(user.equals("p")){
    System.out.println("your move is paper");
  }
  if(user.equals("s")){
    System.out.println("your move is scissors");
  }
 }
 public static void compInput(){
   Random rand=new Random();
   int comp;
   String system;
   comp=rand.nextInt(3);
   if(comp==1){
   V system="rock";
   }
   if(comp==2){
     system="paper";
   }
   if(comp==3){
     system="scissors";
   }
 }
}
```

the above code is for rock paper scissors game, I've tried to compare using the normal way but there is an error which i know why,it because what am trying to compare isn't in the main method...

Comment: _What_ do you want to compare? Your methods do not return a value (`void`) so there is nothing to compare. You can only compare values

Comment: What do you know should be on the main method?

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this `if(userInput().equals(compInput())){`

Comment: You want to compare the return values of two methods, so you'll need to give them a return type (they have the type void at present, which means they return nothing).

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to compare methods, what you want to do, is to compare values returned by those methods.

to do that, you need to change return type for your method, and add return statement

```
public static String compInput(){
   //Existing body   
   return system;
   
 }
```

Comment: You can't compare methods, because they are not objects.

Comment: @RomanC  i never said that "you can compare methods" i just said you don't want to do it.  Also, in java everything is the object, even methods. They live in package `java.lang.reflect`. so technically you CAN do it, you just shouldn't do it

Comment: If the OP said `"How to compare two methods"` then it means a method is an object of return type, that is not true. Also OP didn't use a reflection in the code. So, wanted to compare methods, and instead compared method calls. Since the method is not used in the code, because you cannot assign it to a variable unlikely in other languages it is impossible to  compare methods. It is wrong understanding of methods in Java. Even if you will compare method objects how you will compare the method's code?

Comment: If you consider what OP is trying to achieve, you will see he doesn't want to compare methods, just result. As for comparing methods, I agree with you, you comparing them with reflection does not gives you anything.

Comment: I'm not consider the case of OP's code. It could be errornous, doesn't compile, or syntactically incorrect. OP just doesn't know how to write code to compare methods. No code is driving the answer but the question. And the question exactly asked: `"How to compare two methods"`. It is the point, missing it leads to misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the method returns `void`, it means that you can't get the value because it doesn't exist. The method doesn't return a value. Even if it's a primitive type can't be compared. Thus you can't use it in expressions to evaluate its value. It's not [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), so you can't invoke a method using dot operator.

[`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is the method of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and it's used to compare objects, *not* methods. When creating some classes from that objects are instantiated this method is usually overridden to make comparing objects more relevant to its data that it holds in the fields.

For your better experience using objects try to create some [POJO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) and return it from methods.

Also use [DRY principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) when writing a code. Because if you want to invoke some methods don't do multiple times if it is not necessary.